# Position textareas and buttons in % of the screen

Tags: android, android-studio

I started yesterday with developing for Android. I already know Java, so you don't have to explain general Java things for a beginner.

> Information:
>   IDE: Android Studio (latest)
>   Minimum API: 10

I want to code a fun app where the user types a countdown in a C4 Bomb UI and the bomb's ticking after the input.

I have now the problem that I can not position the elements margin in % of the screen.

Here's an image with the text field, buttons and the margins I calculated with the image dimensions.

How can I do this?

[image: Bomb UI painted]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following algorithm:

```
//declare two variables for width and height of the screen, that you could use later
private int screenWidth;
private int screenHeight;

//first get the size of the screen - call this method in the onCreate method of your Activity
private static void getScreenResolution(Context context){
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    display.getMetrics(metrics);
    screenWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
    screenHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
}

//then use dynamically positioning of the elements as you use LayoutParameters for your elements like this:
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); //width, height
params.setMargins(11*screenWidth/100, 34*screenHeight/100, 0, 0);//left, top, right, bottom - here you could use the % like 11% from screenWidth = 11*screenWidth/100 (all the digits are for example)
//get the element which you want to be positioned at the current position (for example an ImageView)
ImageView myImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myImage);
myImage.setLayoutParams(params);
```

P.S. If your layout is `RelativeLayout`, you should use `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` instead of `Linearlayout.LayoutParams` (just change the word)

Answer (score 0):

You could use weighted layout(empty layout on left and right side of your image then wrap it again for vertical). Let say I want to create an image with margin 25% on both side, then the weight for each empty layout is 1, and for the image is 2.

UPDATE:
here's a little example, the "view" component is just a placeholder for margin
The top and bottom margin is 25% of height, while the left and right margin is 20% of screen's width.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```